# Unable to delete a File in Java

Tags: java, file, delete-file

For whatever reason I am having an issue with File.delete() and File.renameto(File). For example:

```
private void doWork(){
    File inputFile = new File("resources/custom/inputFile.txt");
    System.out.println(inputFile.delete());
}
```

This returns false for me and does not delete the file.

I don't have this file opened or in use anywhere else and I don't understand why I can't delete it. Has anyone else encountered this or have any insight into the problem?

Comment: Do you have permission to delete it?

Comment: Are you sure the file exists and that your path is correct?

Comment: Are you sure the fully-resolved is what you think it is? Do you have delete access rights to the file and directory?

Comment: If you are on Windows and *someone* has it open you can't delete it. I believe Windows can somehow delay file closes, which can cause immediate deletions to fail. A couple of sleeps and retries might help.

Comment: (There's a theme to these simultaneous questions--if nothing else, the takeaway is that when dealing with the filesystem, if you've checked your assumptions, mention them, and if you haven't, do ;)

Comment: Very odd to delete a file under 'resources' too. Are you sure it's a file, not a JAR entry?

Comment: if (!f.canWrite())
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Write protected.")

Comment: isn't there Stream open with this file somewhere?

Comment: @MarianP write permission and delete permission aren't necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a line:

```
System.out.println(inputFile.getCanonicalPath());
```

This will print the actual path (starting from the root) and maybe reveal that it isn't the path you're expecting.

Comment: Make sure your executable is running in the right directory relative to the file you're trying to delete. Using a canonical filename elimnates the proper of executing in the wrong directory.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
private void doWork(){
    File inputFile = new File("resources\\custom\\inputFile.txt");
    System.out.println(inputFile.delete());
}
```

also it will help if you add try and catch

Comment: This won't matter; Java handles converting slashes to the underlying OS's conventions. A try/catch won't help either; if it's a `RuntimeException` it'll bubble up--that the delete returns false pretty much implies there's no exception.

Comment: its a good practice to use try and catch I dont mean for this only , maybe the file is not there and maybe some permissions are missing

Comment: It's only a good practice if you actually plan to *do* something with the exception, otherwise you *shouldn't* catch it. Plus since `SecurityException` is a runtime exception, you may not want to catch it in this location.

Comment: you are right :)
also I didnt know Java convert the slashes 
thanks for the info